# Как сделать коммит в родительском проекте с изменениями из сабмодуля при помощи пре-коммит хука?

Tags: git, git-bash, git-submodule

Разрабатываю pre-commit хук для гита, моделирую ситуация когда разработчик зашел на своей локальной тачке в подмодуль - изменил файл - вернулся в родительский проект и и сделал `git add .` и `git commit` после чего сработал данный хук. Весь текст хука значения не имеет оставлю только нужную часть.

Используя `git submodule foreach`

1. Обращаюсь к подмодулю
2. Индексирую изменения
3. Делаю коммит

Собственно, когда отрабатывает хук я вижу что создался новый коммит в подмодуле
4 шагом я пытаюсь проиндексировать изменения в родительском проекте обращаясб просто `git add deploy` (это название подмодуля)

Вижу сразу два сообщения

1. о том, что изменения проиндексированы и они попадут в коммит
2. что появились новые коммиты в подмодуле и нужно обновить (??????) и что нет изменений которые попадут в коммит

Изменения на сервер не прилетают как видно из скрина №1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скрине №2
я выполняю `git status` чтобы увидеть снова эти сообщения, но осталось только одно сообщение - все готово и индексировано - коммить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скрине №3 я выполняю снова коммит и тогда появляется коммит в родительском проекте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему это не отрабатывает с первого раза?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Я все таки нашел причину, почему это происходит. Дело в том, что git add в pre-commit работает не в каждой версии и обсуждений на этот счет много.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778574/git-add-in-pre-commit-hook-not-staging-file-for-commit

Его частое поведение он индексирует изменения, но они попадут только в следующий коммит. Т.е у вас появляются сразу два противоречивых сообщения, что изменения проиндексированы и одновременно что есть новые изменения, но они не проиндексированы. Просто хочу добавить, что я потратил 2 дня на поиска ответа.